# iPhone simulator graphics corruption

Tags: ios

After a fresh install of High Sierra 10.1, Xcode 9.0 (9A235), Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-829.6 CoreSimulator-494.13.6), on a MBP (15-inch 2017), the simulator has been showing glitchy, corrupt rendering of the screen. It not only happens with my app, it happens with the internal simulator apps and the home screen. It flickers between normal and corrupt when the screen is updating.

So far I have tried:

- Erase all content and settings
- Reboot
- Other devices: iPhone and iPad have these problems, whereas tvOS and watchOS do not have the problem.
- Showing it on an external monitor

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This sounds more like a general hardware/software issue, which would be better suited to [**SuperUser**](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a problem with drivers.

This should be fixed in the future Xcode release *(based on the Apple staff's posts)*:

> A workaround for the graphics driver landed in Xcode 9.1 Beta.  A fix for the underlying driver issue will be in a future macOS update.

[The radar report](http://www.openradar.me/32906330)